# Only ahow error message when error occurs

Tags: php

I am creating a calculator on the web to challenge my ability to think an challenge my creative edge and i got the basics down it works but the issue i am having is the error displaying whem there is no error is just displays when the page loads and then displays the value when the calculator is used can someone please help?

```
<?php

$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$symbol = $_POST['operator'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];
$nulr = "nulrl";

if($nulr === "nulrl"){
if($symbol === "+"){
$output = $value1 + $value2;
} elseif($symbol === "-"){
$output = $value1 - $value2;
} elseif($symbol === "/"){
$output = $value1 / $value2;
} elseif($symbol === "*"){
$output = $value1 * $value2;
} else{
$output = "Error could not perform operation";
}

}
echo $output;
?>
```

EDIT 
Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>The Calculator</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>The Goal</h1>
<p>Through my studies of coding languages i have come to realize that  just about every coding langauage no matter how different the syntax can  handle user input and variables and produce and output. With this being said i wanna make an interactive calculator for each coding language and then advance on each one and see which language can produce the best  calculator!</p>

<main>
<h2>PHP Calculator</h2>
<form method="post">
<input type="number" name="value1" value="value1" class="number-box">
<br>
<select name="operator">
<option value="+">+</option>
<option value="-">-</option>    
<option value="*">*</option>
<option value="/">/</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type ="number" name="value2" value="value2" class="number-box">
<br>
<input type ="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button">
</form>
<?include("calculator.php")?>

<footer>
<h3>Comment Box</h3>
<form method="post" action="comment.php">
<input type="text" value="name" name="name">
<br>
<textarea name="comment">Comments</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button">
</form>

<?php
echo file_get_contents("comments.txt");
?>
</footer>


</main>
</header>
```

EDIT:
Still have not recieved any correct answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['value1']){
    //.......
    else{
        $output = '';
        echo "Error, could not perform operation";
   } 
} 
echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes because you've not added a condition (form submit): you must put at the first line of your PHP code : <?php if(isset($_POST['value1'])){ // here your code   then you close the if at the end }

Answer (score 0):

Put your code like this:

```
$http_post = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ;
if($http_post)
{
        $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
        $symbol = $_POST['operator'];
        $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
        $nulr = "nulrl";

        if($nulr === "nulrl"){
        if($symbol === "+"){
        $output = $value1 + $value2;
        } elseif($symbol === "-"){
        $output = $value1 - $value2;
        } elseif($symbol === "/"){
        $output = $value1 / $value2;
        } elseif($symbol === "*"){
        $output = $value1 * $value2;
        }
        else
        {
            $output = "Error could not perform operation";
        }
}

echo (!empty($output)) ? $output : '';
```

If any errors occur it will appear only after post.

Comment: And if not you will get an undefined variable warning

Comment: Still displays error message as soon as age is loaded

Comment: not possible...this code will only execute when form is submitted. If have modified the code...you were using any js also?

Comment: No javascript as of yet

Comment: tried this $http_post = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ;
if($http_post) ?

Comment: I forgot to restart the server but now im getting this error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /srv/disk5/1819178/www/livewiretech.co.nf/cal/calculator.php on line 27

Comment: please highlight the line?

Comment: Idk which line i dont have an ide i code everything on my iphone 4s